# questions about moving backwards of an intent

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in Android so I get stuck on using the intent method.
I created three java classes, MainActivity give an intent to DetailActivity, in DetailActivity, the textView handles the data coming from MainActivity. DetailActivity give an intent to TheAnswer(All of them have fragments). The problem is, when I click the backwords icon on the top left in TheAnswer. The textView in DetailActivity **is Empty**.
So what should I do to make sure the content from the textView in DetailActivity is well preserved when I move back from TheAnswer?

The content below is the code I written.

MainActivityFragment

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

```
    inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_questions);
    listView.setAdapter(mQuest);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            String element = mQuest.getItem(position).substring(0,3);
            int pointer = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                pointer = pointer * 10 + (int)(element.charAt(i)-'0');
            String data = "";
            StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                    index[pointer-1]);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sbuffer.append(data + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sbuffer.toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

DetailActivityFragment(The class that I am in trouble with)

public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment{

```
private String forecastStr;
TextView text;

public DetailActivityFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    // The detail Activity called via intent.  Inspect the intent for forecast data.
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
        forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text);
        text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        text.setText(forecastStr);
    }

    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottle);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
            // e.g. launch a new activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TheAnswer.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecastStr);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

At last, TheAnswerFragment

public class TheAnswerFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_answer, container, false);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.aa);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is all about storing and restoring the instance state.

Take a look at the Android docs here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

And if you want to make it easier/cleaner potentially you could choose to use this

https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

p.s. Fragments need attention here to, and make sure you take a look at the static Fragment createInstance() pattern so you can store the creation arguments in a bundle attached to the fragment's arguments.

Comment: So I need to add onSaveInstanceState() method, and in onCreateView() method, I check whether the savedInstanceState is null, if it is not, retrive the data from the savedInstanceState, am I right?